# how can you bypass the factory settings password of a display sample tablet

Tags: factory-reset, screen, tablet

I was given a rca 9" tablet that I want to give to my 9 yr old daughter. it powered up but had a display video showing.  I followed video to get back to factory reset but it only gets to a point where it needs a password saying settings locked . I found out more about tablet it had a sticker that said not for retail sale this unit is a display sample and is not for consumer use . it has limited functionality and will not work for normal use. 
am I waisting my time with this tablet ..how can I find out what the password is to unlock settings
it is a rca 9" display tablet model#RCT6293W23
ANY HELP WOULD BE MUCH APPRECIATED

Comment: >"I was given a …" — where did you get it? Was it obtained legally?